# Formatter.js date format

Tags: javascript, regex, date

I'm using formatter.js to format input date. Date has mm/dd/yyyy format. I need that month won't be more than 12 using regex. I'm using formatter method to specify own month pattern.

```
Formatter.addInptType('m', /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/);

<input class="form-control" id="propertyZip" name="zippostal"   data-bind="formatter: {value: Address.ZipPostal,pattern: '{{m/d/y}}' ,persistent: true}">
```

The problem is that when user types in input that using this formatter, it doesn't allow to enter more than one digit.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are your `Formatter.addInptType()` for `y` and `d`? I think you also need to define the `month` as `/\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\b/`. Try to modify your `m` and try with `pattern: '{{m}}/{{99}}/{{9999}}'`. It is possible that you cannot define more than 1 symbol with `Formatter.addInptType` though.

Comment: What's `data-bind` here ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `y` and `d` is just for example. I'm focused on 'm' rule. It should allow digits 1 to 12. It seems that formatter doesn't allow to have more than 1 symbol.

Comment: @Amessihel it's custom data-bind for knockout.js

Comment: So, it seems you need to validate it using other JS language means.

Comment: @podhornyi96, did you try to bind the formatter the way it's told in the documentation ? (`new Formatter(el, opts)`)